# CloudFront Invalidation with Custom Origin and Query String

Tags: string, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am having trouble invalidating CloudFront cached content with query string data.

For example, say I am trying to invalidate the following:

http://d114hh0cykwyb0.cloudfront.net/imagesizer.php?h=80&src=/images/foo.jpg

I use the AWS SDK to send the invalidation path, which is:
/imagesizer.php?h=80&src=/images/foo.jpg

I'll then go into the AWS Console->CloudFront->Distribution Settings->Invalidations

I see my new invalidation request.  If I see the 'Details' on it, the Object Paths says:
/imagesizer.php%3Fh%3D80%26src%3D/images/foo.jpg

So the path has been encoded.  However, after the invalidation has been Completed,
http://d114hh0cykwyb0.cloudfront.net/imagesizer.php?h=80&src=/images/foo.jpg
remains the same.

I also tried using the 'Create Invalidation' from within the AWS Console using the path:
/imagesizer.php?h=80&src=/images/foo.jpg

but I get an XML parse error (because the URL is not encoded).

Has anyone dealt with this kind of issue before?  Were you able to find a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Does object expiration with query string works via the API for anyone? I could not get it to work, and I suspect they have not extended the invalidation API to support query strings.

Answer (score 0):

These days the answer is yes - CloudFront does support invalidations for forwarded query strings. The following is from [The CloudFront Developer Guide - Invalidations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidation-specifying-objects).

> Forwarding query strings
>
> If you configured CloudFront to forward query strings to your origin, you must include the query strings when invalidating files, as
> shown in the following examples:
>
> ```
>     /images/image.jpg?parameter1=a
>
>     /images/image.jpg?parameter1=b
> ```
>
> If client requests include five different query strings for the same file, you can either invalidate the file five times, once for
> each query string, or you can use the * wildcard in the invalidation
> path, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> /images/image.jpg*
> ```

Answer (score -5):

a very easy way to use invalidation is the use of third party tools. Personally i use CloudBerry - > http://www.cloudberrylab.com/